# How to escape characters in ofbiz display-entity | XSS in Ofbiz

Tags: forms, escaping, entity, xss, ofbiz

Ofbiz form: Need to escape characters from description column in a display-entity tag to avoid XSS attacks:

```
<display-entity entity-name="Table" description="${description}" >
```

I tried to use bsh, as following:

```
<display-entity entity-name="Table" description="${bsh: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(&quot;${description}&quot;)}">
```

But I get this error:

```
Error rendering screen [component://my/widget/CommonScreens.xml#GlobalDecorator]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has been flagged as immutable (unchangeable), probably because it came from an Entity Engine cache. Cannot set a value in an immutable entity object. 
(This object has been flagged as immutable (unchangeable), probably because it came from an Entity Engine cache. Cannot set a value in an immutable entity object.)
```

Exists a solution here to escape chars in description?

Answer (score 0):

There is no XSS issue there as explained at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-6506 So no needs to escape, it's automatically done by OFBiz

Comment: `<display-entity entity-name="Table" description="XSS from DB">`       

If we submit this script: `<input type="image" src="javascript:alert('XSS');">` as value for description column in DB and after that we go on this form, appears popup.

Exists here a way to escape chars in description attribute from `<display-entity` ?

Answer (score 0):

We recently committed a patch for this XSS vulnerability to Scipio ERP (an ofbiz fork):

https://github.com/ilscipio/scipio-erp/commit/cf7e8ef40af06e2903fb50a3f708a455ffd88c2a

It may be worth checking it out (www.scipioerp.com).